# python как изменить текст на картинке?

Tags: python, изображения, psd

нужно создать кучу грамот по шаблону (psd tiff не принципиально) с изменяющимся фио и номером и сохранить каждый в отдельный jpg

как лучше реализовать и с помощью каких инструментов? не могу найти нормальных библиотек для редактирования изображений

Answer (score 3):

с помощью PIL, например. Минимально, Вам понадобится импортировать оттуда Image, ImageFont (для подключения truetype-шрифта) и ImageDraw. Сохраняете бланк грамоты без текста, а потом рисуете текст поверх. Примерно так:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

# определяете шрифт
font = ImageFont.trueType('/путь/до/файла/со/шрифтом.ttf')

# определяете положение текста на картинке
text_position = (150, 150)

# цвет текста, RGB
text_color = (255,0,0)

# собственно, сам текст
text = 'Фамилия Имя Отчество'

# загружаете фоновое изображение
img = Image.open('blank.jpg')

# определяете объект для рисования
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# добавляем текст
draw.text(text_position, text, text_color, font)

# сохраняем новое изображение
img.save('blank_with_text.jpg')
```

Вкратце, как то так... Вероятно, положение и размер текста придется подбирать экспериментально.

Comment: Можно еще использовать  imagemagick + bash/cmd скрипт.