# Как добавить текст на картинку?

Tags: python, pillow, обработка-изображений

Знаю, вопрос уже [задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649889), но мне нужна помощь с текстом: дело в том, что я хочу сделать к этому обводку шрифта (то есть сам текст красный, но каждая буква с белой обводкой). Ещё нужно чтобы этот текст центрировался (был выровнен по центру), имел границы по высоте, а также мог адаптироваться по размеру. Кто поможет?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: Вы задали целых четыре никак не связанных вопроса - разделите их

Comment: @andreymal тут один вопрос!

Comment: @eri 1) Обводка; 2) Центрирование; 3) Границы; 4) Адаптация. Ну ладно, 3 и 4 может связаны, а 1 и 2 точно отдельные

Comment: 1) "кто поможет?"

Comment: @eri вот из-за таких как вы вместо базы знаний получается непонятно что)

Comment: честно была схожая задача: на картинке с бокалами пива подписать цену и наименование и менять с учетом того что есть на точке на данный момент. питоном заполняем шаблон и хромом рендерится в картинку. картинка на флешку - флешка в "тупой" телек с функцией фоторамки

Answer (score 1):

Pil тут не очень поможет. Я бы брал SVG, HTML или PDF. На языке разметрки нужно адаптивно сверстать документ-шаблон. Потом питоном заменяешь в шаблоне картинку на нужную. Далее рендерить и скриншотить. В случае svg или html - коммандной строкой хрома это проще всего.

Comment: При желании всё это можно реализовать через PIL, но придётся заморочиться

Comment: Делал подобное с помощью PyCairo